# Find a basis for each of the following subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$W = \{(x,y,z)|x-2y+5z=0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$

Am I suppose to do a Matrix with the $3$ vectors and equal it to the $x-2y+5$z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

let $y=s$, let $z=t$.

Express $x$ in terms of $s,t$.

Write $(x,y,z) = s(a_1,a_2,a_3)+t(b_1,b_2, b_3)$.

Comment: So I solve for x on the equation then replace on the (x,y,z), then is the answer {(1,0,0),(2,1,0),(-5,0,1)}?

Comment: what do you get as you express $x$ in terms of $s$ and $t$.

Comment: x=2s-5r -> this means x is a free variable then y(2,1,0) and z(-5,0,1) then basis is {(2,1,0),(-5,0,1)}?    Sorry if I misuderstand

Comment: you have gotten the right vectors, do check that they are linearly independent.